# How to connect a bitcoin node to a complete node through the local network?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I currently have a full bitcoin node on my local network and I would like to create another node but only update it by local network.

I have tried with: 
`./bitcoind -connect<iplocal>` 
`./bitcoind -addnode<iplocal>` 
but I get the following error 
`` syntax error near unexpected token `newline' ``
I appreciate your help.

Comment: You need an equals sign (`=`) after `-connect`.

Comment: i'm goint to try ```./bitcoin-qt -connect="iplocal"```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, your command needs to be `./bitcoind -connect=<iplocal>`

`-connect=` will connect ONLY to that specified node. `-addnode=` will connect to the specified node in addition to attempting to connect to global nodes. If you're bootstrapping a new node either will work